# My docker restassured image is not running in container

Tags: java, docker, rest-assured

Below is my dockerFile

```
FROM maven:3.3-jdk-8
COPY src/test/java /apitesting/Restassured/src/test/java
COPY pom.xml /apitesting/Restassured/pom.xml
WORKDIR /apitesting/Restassured
ENTRYPOINT mvn clean test
```

I have API RestAssured code in it, when i run `mvn clean test` in my local it is working fine.

But after i created the docker image using below command, i tried to run the image their are no failures and test are also not running.

Step 1 : Create a docker image

```
docker build -t koushick1996/myapiimage:2 .
```

Step 2 : run the image

```
docker run koushick1996/myapiimage:2
```

Result:
No test are running. [image]

Note : [Edit] - After i downgraded the Junit version from 5 to 4 the docker image is able to run now and able to push the image as well.
https://hub.docker.com/r/koushick1996/myapiimage/tags

Can you help me the issue where iam facing the issue in Junit5 version

Also please find the source code for SampleAPITest.java

```
    package SampleTestDocker;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Order;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestMethodOrder;

import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath;

import io.restassured.response.Response;

import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;

import java.util.Scanner;

@TestMethodOrder(OrderAnnotation.class)
public class SampleAPITest {




static String requestbodyget = null;
static String userId = null;


public static void generateReq() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    GenerateRequest requestbody = new GenerateRequest();
    String user = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(7);
    requestbody.setUserName(user+"ai");
    String password = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(7);
    requestbody.setPassword(password+"ai@!12345");
    requestbodyget = requestbody.getJsonBody(requestbody.getUserName(),requestbody.getPassword());
    System.out.println(requestbodyget);
}


@Test
@Order(1)
public void hitpostAPITocreateUser() throws InterruptedException {
    
    generateReq();
    
    
    String endpoint = "https://bookstore.toolsqa.com/Account/v1/User";
    
    Response res = given().
            accept("application/json")
            .contentType("application/json").
    body(requestbodyget)
    .post(endpoint);
    
    String getResponseBody = res.getBody().asPrettyString();
    
    System.out.println("The request is : " + requestbodyget);
    System.out.println("The API Endpoint is : " + endpoint);
    System.out.println("The response headers are : " + res.getHeaders());
    System.out.println("The Response body is : " + getResponseBody);
    System.out.println("The status code is : " + res.getStatusCode());
    
    userId = JsonPath.parse(getResponseBody).read("$.userID");
    
    System.out.println("The User id is :" + userId);
    
    Thread.sleep(15000);
        
}


@Test
@Order(2)
public void hitpostAPItoGenerateTokenToAuthorize() {
    
    String endpoint = "https://bookstore.toolsqa.com/Account/v1/GenerateToken";
    
    Response res = given().
            accept("application/json")
            .contentType("application/json").
    body(requestbodyget)
    .post(endpoint);
    
    String getResponseBody = res.getBody().asPrettyString();
    
    
    System.out.println("The request is : " + requestbodyget);
    System.out.println("The API Endpoint is : " + endpoint);
    System.out.println("The response headers are : " + res.getHeaders());
    System.out.println("The Response body is : " + getResponseBody);
    System.out.println("The status code is : " + res.getStatusCode());
    
}


@Test
@Order(3)
public void hitpostAPItoAuthorize() {
    
    String endpoint = "https://bookstore.toolsqa.com/Account/v1/Authorized";
    
    Response res = given().
            accept("application/json")
            .contentType("application/json").
    body(requestbodyget)
    .post(endpoint);
    
    String getResponseBody = res.getBody().asPrettyString();
    
    System.out.println("The request is : " + requestbodyget);
    System.out.println("The API Endpoint is : " + endpoint);
    System.out.println("The response headers are : " + res.getHeaders());
    System.out.println("The Response body is : " + getResponseBody);
    System.out.println("The status code is : " + res.getStatusCode());
    
}



@Test
@Order(4)
public void hitgetAPIafterAuthorize() {
    
    String endpoint = "https://bookstore.toolsqa.com/Account/v1/User/"+userId;
    
    Response res = given()
    .accept("application/json")
    .contentType("application/json")
    .get(endpoint);
    
    String getResponseBody = res.getBody().asPrettyString();
    
    System.out.println("The request is : " + requestbodyget);
    System.out.println("The API Endpoint is : " + endpoint);
    System.out.println("The response headers are : " + res.getHeaders());
    System.out.println("The Response body is : " + getResponseBody);
    System.out.println("The status code is : " + res.getStatusCode());
}


}
```

pom.xml

```
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>SampleRestAssured</groupId>
  <artifactId>SampleRestAssured</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  
  
  
  <dependencies>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
    <version>5.9.3</version>
</dependency>



<dependency>
    <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.1</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.0</version>
</dependency>

  
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: It seems that you're using wrong annotation of JUnit 5. Could you add source code of `SampleAPITest`, specially the import part.

Comment: @lucas-nguyen-17 added source code. But now i have created the image after downgraded to Junit 4 it is working fine. i faced the above issue when the junit version is 5

Comment: Everything seems correct to me. Could you add pom.xml as well?

Comment: @lucas-nguyen-17 added pom.xml. Actually if you see the pom.xml file i was using junit 5 , the code was working fine in local when i run from container. The tests was not running. So, to check i have downgraded the junit 5 to 4 and published in the version 2  in the below image
koushick1996/myapiimage:2

Comment: What I concern here is `junit-jupiter-api` is just API declaration, no engine to do actual job at all. It's better to use https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter to have all JUnit5 module. Not sure it can solve your problem, but it's worth to try.